# ant task to delete files and directory that start with the same name

Tags: ant

In my folder `example`

I have a directory called `test`. It contains many subfolders
I also have files called `test.properties` and `test.properties.sample`

I am trying to create an ant script to remove the files and directory

Do I have to have 3 different tasks to delete these files?

For example

```
<delete dir="test" />
<delete file="test.properties" />
<delete file="test.properties.sample" />
```

I would rather have something like

```
<delete dir="test*" />
```

so it deletes everything in the folder that starts with `test`

Answer (score 19):

Use a `fileset` to select files with a pattern, a `dirset` to select directories with a pattern.

This should do the job:

```
<delete>
    <dirset dir="${basedir}" includes="test*" />
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="test*" />
</delete>
```